# Log4j not working properly

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j for my project. It's not working when I use the jar. When I added the vm arg  `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to my debug configuration, I got this -

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@644d46.
    log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/modia1/.m2/repository/ca/uhn/hapi/hapi-hl7overhttp/2.2/hapi-hl7overhttp-2.2.jar!/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
    log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
    log4j: System property is :null
    log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
    log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
    log4j: debug attribute= "null".
    log4j: Ignoring debug attribute.
    log4j: reset attribute= "false".
    log4j: Threshold ="null".
    log4j: Level value for root is  [debug].
    log4j: root level set to DEBUG
    log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
    log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
    log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
    log4j: Adding appender named [stdout] to category [root].
```

But I have put the log4j properties file in src/main/resources & the project folder. But still it's using some other logger configuration. How can I make it use my properties file?

Comment: You can place properties file in `/resources` directory.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the log4j.xml or log4j.properties under the following path:

/yourapp/src/main/java/

can you please post a screen shot on the file hierarchy of the project ?

Comment: there's your problem you should put the log4j.xml under src :)

Comment: I'm using log4j.properties file, not xml. You mean src/main/java?

Comment: yes exactly you should put log4j.properties under src/main/java

Comment: is it giving you the same error ? can you copy paste the error ?

Comment: I'm using PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties"). It's working with that.